# Python Telegram Bot and Pandas - reply_text show "\n" Instead of new line

Tags: pandas, python-telegram-bot

I have a simple Telegram Bot with python-telegram-bot package and i use pandas to import a csv:

`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`

| key | text |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | text1 \n text2 \n text3 |
| . | some \n text |
| . | other \n text |
| 99 | text4 \n text5 \n text6 |

Then I do a search inside the dataframe from user message:

`answer = df['text'].str.contains(update.message.text, case=False)]`

and the bot sends a reply message to the user:

`await update.message.reply_text(answer)`

but the output is showing the "\n" tag:

```
text1 \n text2 \n text3
```

and I want to show the text:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

I'm struggling with this problem. Before dataframe I used TinyDb and everything worked fine.
How can I resolve?

Thanks

I try to change dtype of column to string, to export csv to list, encoding of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what happened in your case, but it worked for me.

[Image result in telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibu81.jpg)

```py
import pandas as pd

# I am using json format for my case
data = [
    {"key": "01", "text": "text1 \n text2 \n text3"},
    {"key": "01", "text": "some \n text"},
    {"key": "02", "text": "other \n text"},
    {"key": "99", "text": "text4 \n text5 \n text6"},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# ...

answer = df[df["text"].str.contains("some", case=False)]
# answer = df[df["text"].str.contains(update.message.text, case=False)]

if not answer.empty:
    print(answer.values[0][1].encode())  # check raw text
    # out: b'some \n text'
    print(type(answer.values[0][1]))  # check type
    # out: <class 'str'>
    await update.message.reply_text(answer.values[0][1])
```

With csv data:

```
key,text
01,text1 \n text2 \n text3
01,some \n text
02,other \n text
99,text4 \n text5 \n text6
101,this is emoji \n ✅ \n \U0001F600\
```

```py
# ...
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

answer = df[df["text"].str.contains("some", case=False)]

if not answer.empty:
    print(answer.values[0][1].encode())  # check raw text
    # out: b'some \n text'
    print(type(answer.values[0][1]))  # check type
    # out: <class 'str'>
    print(answer.values[0][1])  # print text
    # out: some \n text
    print(answer.values[0][1].replace("\\n", "\n"))  # replace text
    # out: some 
    #       text

    # ...
```

Output:

```bash
b'some \\n text'
<class 'str'>
some \n text
some 
 text
```

When we work with csv, we will get `\\n`, we can change `\\n` to `\n` to get the result we need.

```py
print(answer.values[0][1].replace("\\n", "\n"))  # replace text
```

Working with unicode, we need a unicode escape sequence and replace it with Unicode characters using the `unicode_escape` codec.

A simple way we can use a regex expression like that:

```py
import re

def replace_unicode_escape(text):
    def replace(match):
        return match.group(0).encode().decode("unicode_escape")

    text = re.sub(r"\\n", "\n", text)
    return re.sub(r"\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}", replace, text)
```

```py
# ...

if not answer.empty:
    # ...

    print(replace_unicode_escape(answer.values[0][1]))  # replace text
    # out: this is emoji
    #       ✅
    #       

    # ...
```

Output:

```bash
b'this is emoji \\n \xe2\x9c\x85 \\n \\U0001F600'
<class 'str'>
this is emoji \n ✅ \n \U0001F600
this is emoji 
 ✅
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is when i import that data from csv file. If i create the dataframe inside python everything works well.

Comment: In csv data you will get `\\n` you can replace it with `\n`.

Comment: It works! Thank you. With  .replace('\\n', '\n'). But if i have even some emoji unicode?

Comment: Working with unicode, we need a unicode escape sequence and replace it with Unicode characters using the `unicode_escape` codec.